# Should StreamEx parallelism work when using takeWhile?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, streamex

I have a stream that I create like this:

```
StreamEx.generate(new MySupplier<List<Entity>>())
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(Entity::getName)
        .map(name -> ...)
        .. // more stuff
```

I can change this to work in parallel by just adding `parallel`:

```
StreamEx.generate(new MySupplier<List<Entity>>())
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(Entity::getName)
        .map(name -> ...)
        .parallel()
        .. // more stuff
```

But I also want to add a `takeWhile` condition to make the stream stop:

```
StreamEx.generate(new MySupplier<List<Entity>>())
        .takeWhile(not(List::isEmpty))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(Entity::getName)
        .map(name -> ...)
        .parallel()
        .. // more stuff
```

But as soon as I add the `takeWhile` the stream seems to become sequential (at least it's only processed by one thread). According to the [javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/one.util/streamex/0.6.4/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) of `takeWhile`, if I understand it correctly, should work with parallel streams. Am I doing something wrong or is this according to design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in normal Stream API if something works in parallel, it does not mean that it works efficiently. The javadoc states that:

> While this operation is quite cheap for sequential stream, it can be quite expensive on parallel pipelines.

Actually you want to use `takeWhile` with unordered stream which *could* be optimized specially, but does not optimized currently, so this could be considered as a defect. I will try to fix this (I'm the StreamEx author).

**Update**: fixed in version 0.6.5

Comment: Thanks! I've added an issue for it on the issue tracker: https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/issues/142

Comment: @Johan, fixed in version 0.6.5